# Getting Syntax error when querying MySQL DB in Java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to return all the information on one row of a database but I keep getting a syntax error and I'm not sure why. If I want, I can return all the information in the database no problem but I keep running into issues trying to get just one row. Also, how does one query a table row that may have spaces in it? Here's the relevant code

```
    package core;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DBConnection {

    private Connection con;
    private static Statement statement;
    private static ResultSet resultSet;
    public  static DBConnection connection;
    private static ResultSetMetaData meta;
    private static HashMap<String,Party> map;

    public static Party party;

    private DBConnection()
    {
        try 
        {
            map = new HashMap<String,Party>();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://blah/reddb", "blah",
                    "blah");
            statement = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Error: "+e);
        }
    }
            //do not worry about this method it works fine, I put it here so prove that the db connection is not the problem. When this method is run I can get all the contents. See readOneParty() for issue
    public static void readAllData() //this method works fine
    {
        if(connection == null)
        {
            connection = new DBConnection();
        }
        try
        {
            map.clear();
            String query = "(SELECT * FROM PureServlet)";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
            String columnName, value, partyName;
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                partyName = resultSet.getString("PARTY_NAME");
                map.put(partyName, new Party()); //this is the map that keeps track of all parties
                party = map.get(partyName);
                for(int j=1;j<=meta.getColumnCount();j++) //necessary to start at j=1 because of MySQL index starting at 1
                {
                    columnName = meta.getColumnLabel(j);
                    value = resultSet.getString(columnName);
                    party.getPartyInfo().put(columnName, value); //this is the hashmap within the party that keeps 
                    //track of the individual values. The column Name = label, value is the value
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
            //this is the method where I'm getting an exception
    public static Party readOneParty(String partyName)
    {
        if(connection==null)
        {
            connection = new DBConnection();
        }
        try
        {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME="+partyName;
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query); //exception occurs here
            meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
            String columnName, value;
            Party party = new Party();
            for(int j=1;j<=meta.getColumnCount();j++) //necessary to start at j=1 because of MySQL index starting at 1
            {
                columnName = meta.getColumnLabel(j);
                value = resultSet.getString(columnName);
                party.getPartyInfo().put(columnName, value); //this is the hashmap within the party that keeps 
                //track of the individual values. The column Name = label, value is the value
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return party;
    }
    public static HashMap<String,Party> getPartyCollection()
    {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Here's the error I get when trying to return a party with no spaces:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'VSN' in 'where clause'
```

Here's the error I get when there are spaces in the party:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' GOURMET PATISSERIE' at line 1
```

Comment: And where is the syntax error?

Comment: **Where** do you get the error? What does it say?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: connection variable is not defined in your code. You have declared and initialized a varible 'con' instead.

Comment: Con is my connection variable, it's initialized in the constructor. The connection is not the problem, I'm capable of accessing the table as evident by the ability to get all the contents of the database, however when I try to return the contents from just one row based on the party_name column i get a syntax error

Comment: A string in SQL must be between apostrophes: `PARTY_NAME='VSN'`. Really better to use a prepared statement (`PARTY_NAME=?`) as that also escapes any apostrophe in the string.

Comment: Okay I'll look into prepared statements in the meantime will something like
 `String query = "SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME="+"'"+partyName+"'";`

work

Comment: Joop, if you make yours a question I'll give you the check mark, your answer was very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a naive perspective, you are missing quotes around the string, so change:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME="+partyName;
```

to this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME = '" + partyName + "'";
```

Without this change, you may get a query String that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME = some value
```

which would be invalid SQL - you need:

```
SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME = 'some value'
```

---

However, you're better to use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders, and let JDBC supply quotes, and escaping of quotes for string values of like `O'Brien`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME=?");
ps.setString(1, partyName);
resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I'll give you the check, the answer is in the comments as well though

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the party name wants a space in front of it; otherwise, it all looks like one big name.

Try:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM PureServlet WHERE PARTY_NAME = " + partyName;
```